# Extract string part between single quotes from formula's divisor

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
select ATTRFormula,
       Devider_col=substring(attrformula,charindex('/',ATTRFormula)+9,len(attrformula)-2)
from temp_mst_measure 
where attrtype='derived' 
and attrformula like '%/%'
```

ex:

`DMFunc('Food_01')/DMFunc('BTP_01')` this is Attrformula.

`BTP_01')` this is Devider_col

how to remove last two characters `')` in Devider_col

Comment: AtrrFormula
DMFunc('Food_01')/DMFunc('BTP_01')
DMFunc('Food_02')/DMFunc('BTP_01')
DMFunc('EGY_MAN_CON_001')/DMFunc('SI_003')

Divider_col
BTP_01')
BTP_01')
SI_003') 

how to remove last two characters from derived_col(    ')    )

Comment: DMFunc('Food_01')/DMFunc('BTP_01')    this is Attrformula. i want to extract BTP_01 only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace those characters with an empty string with `REPLACE`.

```
select ATTRFormula,
       Devider_col=
        REPLACE(
            substring(attrformula,charindex('/',ATTRFormula)+9,len(attrformula)-2),
            ''')',
            '')
from temp_mst_measure 
where attrtype='derived' 
and attrformula like '%/%'
```

Comment: thank you EzLo. It's working...... but why you are replacing that single apostrophe?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is like below, get the divisor part, replace single quote with dot, use parsename to get what you want.
Read up on [**Parsename**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

also see <kbd>**[live demo](http://rextester.com/NMBHY52783)**</kbd>

```
select ATTRFormula,
       parsename(
           replace(substring(ATTRFormula,charindex('/',ATTRFormula)+1, len(ATTRFormula)-charindex('/',ATTRFormula)),'''','.')
                   ,2)
from temp_mst_measure 
where attrtype='derived' 
and attrformula like '%/%'
```

Comment: I have one doubt. why are you  replacing that single apostrophe?

Comment: @manjunathk To utilize the wizardry of SQL Parsename function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select substring(AttrFormula, [start], [end] - [start]) from (
    select AttrFormula, [start], charindex('''', AttrFormula, [start] + 1) [end] from (
        select AttrFormula, charindex('''', AttrFormula, charindex('/', AttrFormula, 1)) + 1 [start]
        from MY_TABLE
    ) a
) a
```

Comment: it is working for single row. but i have a column called AttrFormula. is it possible to extract each column?

Comment: @manjunathk Yes! Just replace every occurence of `@s` to `AttrFormula` and remove declaration of variable `declare....` :) Also accept answer if it solved the problem :)

Comment: but where I need to mention table name?

Comment: it's giving error as Invalid column name 'AttrFormula'